# How to make the android Bluetooth keep scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi this is my first time posting.
Im making an android application that only discover Bluetooth device by using the friendly name and the mac address . Not pairing.

The problem im facing is my device fail to detect new device that enter the range after is start the scan about 10 to 12 second.

```
final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
             // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
             BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
             // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
            // System.out.println(device.getAddress());

             for(int i=0;i<listmac.size();i++)
             {
                 if(listmac.get(i).equals(device.getAddress())){
                    System.out.println(listname.get(i));
                    myListView.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
             } 
        }
    }
};

public void find(View view) {
       if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
           // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
           myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
       }
       else {
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
            isBreceiverRegisted = true;
        }    
   }

 public void off(){
      myBluetoothAdapter.disable();

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned off",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Sorry for my broke english

Answer (score 0):

Simply because the discovery task has a timeout to prevent endless searched.
To be able to detect that discovery ended  you need add this intent

```
if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
      // When discovery is finished , start discovery again  
         myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); 
      } 
    }
```

Be very careful in general about accidentally leaving your device in discovery-mode. **Performing device discovery is a heavy procedure for the Bluetooth adapter and will consume a lot of its resources.**